# Using . vs () for certain functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python3 and I'm confused with the syntax for certain functions.

For example, to find the length of a string, the syntax is:

```
len(string_variable)
```

But for other functions like to append an element to a list it is:

```
list_variable.append(x)
```

If both of them are functions why can't I use them as `string_variable.len() or append(list_variable, x)`

Comment: It'll be worth having a read through: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/7/9/python-and-pola/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a [number of predefined functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) (built-in functions) that can be called without importing any additional packages.  `len` is one of those functions, it gives the number of elements an object contains.

A function that is attached to an object is called a method.  Methods are accessible using the dot notation you mentioned: `object.method()`  A method typically operates on the object itself, or uses information in the object as part of its operation.

Many objects implement special methods that allows the built-in functions to return what is expected.  As as example, `len(string_var)` can also be accessed by calling the method `string_var.__len__()`

```py
string_var = 'hello world'
len(string_var) == string_var.__len__()
# returns:
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The len() function is a  built-in function. If the function were developed only for a specific class it would be called a class method. Class methods can be called without creating an instance of the class. You can only operate on class members.

On the other hand, append(x) function is an Instance method. They require an instance of the class to exist before they can be called.

You'll find [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/class-method-vs-static-method-in-python) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-method-vs-static-method-python/) a detailed explanation about the differences.

Comment: `len` is not a class method.  It is a built-in function.

Comment: Thanks @James for the correction. Anyway, I think that the question is related to the differences between the instance methods and class methods. Please check if is the explanation is better now.

Answer (score 0):

Functions that are associated with an object are method functions and operate on the object (example you gave the append appends to the list given).  They are associated via the . operation that indicates they are methods associated with an instance. functions that are not associated with an object (example len()) operate with the parameters passed to them.  They are typically called just functions.

There is no specific reason that what you say could not appear in the libraries provided. its just that they logical organization based on usage, etc has resulted in the current library of functions and object instance methods.